# Google Universal Analytics Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-analytics

I'm trying to code a javascript snippet tracking form submits, with the least amount of inconvenience to the visitor. The flow I'm trying to program is this.

> 1. The user clicks on submit or presses enter to submit a form (leave a comment for example).
> 2. The attached form submit handler catches this event and prevent the form from submitting.
> 3. The script send an google analytics event, upon hitting the callback (i don't want to use the timeout method), the handler is
>      removed and the form is submitted

However, the problem I'm facing is that the form is not (re)submitted upon hitting the google analytics callback. The handler is removed, because submitting the form manually a second time results in normal behaviour.

The code I have is:

```
var formSubmitHandler = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    ga('send', 'event', 'Form Submit', 'Form Submit', 'Form Submit', 
        {'hitCallback':
            function () {
                jQuery(event.target).submit();
            }
        });

    return false;
}

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    if (typeof(ga)==='undefined')
        return;
    jQuery('form').one('submit',formSubmitHandler);
});
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `submit` the form, not trigger the `submit` event again.

Please change:

```
jQuery(event.target).submit();
```

To:

```
event.target.submit();
```

Comment: I see, however,this results in an function not defined error. Apparently this is due the case of an input button named submit inside the form. Is there any way in which I can do this regardless if there is an input button named submit present?

Comment: Not that I know of. You may want to rename that input button.